# making a program to add a list of names in 2d array actually I just made a part of it and I have a lot of errors

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop, multidimensional-array, while-loop

my code is:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char names[10][31];
    int u=0;
    char new[31];
    int ctr=1;
    int notInList=0;
    int y=0;
    int i=0;
    char *p;

    strcpy(names[0],"mahmoud");

    while(1)
    {
        printf("\t\t§§§Menu items§§§\n");
        printf("1==>enter a new name\n");
        printf("2==>search for a name\n");
        printf("3==>delete a name from the list\n");
        printf("Note !!.. ((if you want to exit the program press(1)and  then type ((exit))\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%i",&u);
        notInList=1;
        if(u==1)
        {
            printf("please enter a name : ");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(new);
            _strlwr(new);
            if(strcmp(new,"exit")==0) 
            {
                printf("bye bye\n");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                notInList=1;
                for(int i=0;i<=ctr;i++)
                {

                    p=strstr(new,names[i]);
                    if(strcmp(new,names[i])==0)
                    {
                        printf("the name is already exist\n");
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (p)
                    {
                        printf("did you mean (( %s ))\n",names[i]);
                        printf("1==>yes\n");
                        printf("2==>no\n");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        scanf("%d",&y);
                        if(y==1)
                        {
                            printf("the name is already exist\n");
                            break;
                        }
                        else if(y==2)
                        {
                            notInList=0;
                            strcpy(new,names[ctr]);
                            ctr++;
                            break;
                        }
                        else printf("plz enter a number from the list");
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        notInList=0;
                    }
                }
                    if(notInList==0)
                    {
                        strcpy(new,names[ctr]);
                        ctr++;
                        for(int i=0;i<ctr;i++);
                        {
                            printf("%d==>%s\n",i+1,names[i]);
                        }
                    }
                //  break;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

---

the first problem is: when I enter ( 1) and then add a name is similar to the first name it printf to me did you mean (  )//// without a name

---

the second is when I want to add a new name it doesn't please help me

---

notice that he program is not finished only the first choise

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<=ctr;i++)` should be `for(int i=0;i<ctr;i++)`. Otherwise you go one index too far and end up accessing an invalid `names` entry.

Comment: the `gets()` function has been depreciated for years and is non existent in the latest C standard.  Strongly suggest replacing any call to `gets()` with a call to `fgets()`  (which does have a different set of parameters.

Comment: the posted code has a missing closing brace '}'.   I'm not exactly sure where it needs to be added

Comment: for readability and ease of understanding by us humans: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) with a single blank line.  2) indent the code (suggest 4 spaces, never tabs) after every opening brace "{'  un-indent the code before every closing brace '}'

Comment: what//where is the function: `_strlwr()` 1) it is not in the C libraries. 2) note that symbols starting with double underscore, or underscore and a capital letter, are unconditionally reserved for the implementation. Yes, system headers use names with double underscores — they're part of the implementation and aren't allowed to pollute your namespace. You shouldn't pollute their namespace. For all practical purposes, and multiple counter-examples notwithstanding, treat names starting with underscore as reserved for the implementation.

Comment: thanks but it realy did not fix my problem plz help me